# 'CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, webview2

I'm new to C# and the WebView2 control, and I'm trying to make something happen when a webpage inside the control finishes loading.

`webView.NavigationCompleted += new CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs(WebView_NavigationCompleted);`

The code above throws a CS1729 error. What is the correct way to implement what I'm trying to accomplish? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Show your event handler (`WebView_NavigationCompleted`). We can't guess what you have.

Comment: You should be able to do: `webView.NavigationCompleted += WebView_NavigationCompleted;`.

Comment: Would you share the error name and message? That's much easier to find. Also, make sure you look at the relevant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/ I suspect the WebView runtime isn't fully initialized. The documentation explains how to wait for that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [WebView2 C# sample apps](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/). It has a C# example of just what you're trying to do.

[Registering the event handler](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/80c591545b44d6326239706fd23d1bd1bd00d5e4/SampleApps/WebView2WpfBrowser/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L112)

```cs
            control.NavigationCompleted += WebView_NavigationCompleted;
```

[The event handler](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/80c591545b44d6326239706fd23d1bd1bd00d5e4/SampleApps/WebView2WpfBrowser/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L1206)

```cs
        void WebView_NavigationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // ...
        }
```

See also [Navigation Events documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/navigation-events).